# Select element with xpath using jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, html

Can any one help me to select text next to img tag. In below case, I assuming answer is "USERNAME".

Path:

> /html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div/ul/li/a/img

```
<div id="side-bar">
<ul>
<li alt="User options">
<a href="#" name="nav1">
<img src="myprofile.png"/> USERNAME
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have written:

```
var abc = $( "div#side-bar ul li" ).find('a').find('img').text();
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your image tag an `id = "img1"` & try this..

```
$("#img1").parent().text()
```

Or Try this also..

```
$("div#side-bar ul li").find('a').find('img').parent().text()
```

Comment: Thanks, actually i am using greasemonkey script to return user name on page load, i cant edit original html source code mentioned in above.